# Problems in connection to webserver using Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, windows

I have installed Ruby on Rails and have no programming experience. I wanted to connect to webserver as I want to run a demo application.

I did:

```
$ rails server
```

BUT after that my command prompt stops working, meaning that I can not continue (e.g. I can not type a command).

Can anyone give me advice on what to do next?

[image: console screen shot showing <code>rails s</code> output]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. When you start the rails server it takes over the terminal that you were using to print out the log. You will not be able to enter new commands until you either:

1. kill the server
2. run the server in the background (hit CTRL+Z and type "bg")

You could also start the server in background mode with: `rails script/server &`

However - I recommend opening a second terminal screen for commands, as watching the log is very useful for debugging purposes.

Comment: No problems.  If one of the answers helped you the most - it's Good Practice to "accept" it, which you can do by clicking on the little "tick" icon that appears on the left of the answer. "accepting" answers makes answerers happy which makes it more likely for you to get help the next time you need to ask a question.

Answer (score 2):

I is normal. You have two options, or detach server from console using `-d` flag or start another concole and work inside there. I prefer the second way because it easier to restart server and check logs when log is outputted on terminal also.

Answer (score 0):

Start your browser and go to `http://localhost:3000/` as You already did according to your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

one more option is goto

```
    http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

try this...